# Dirichlet Series of a given sequence

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, riemann-zeta, mobius-inversion

I am trying to calculate the dirichlet generating function of $(p(n)q( \log(n)))_{n \geq 1}$ where $p,q$ are arbitary polynoms. First I calculated the dirichlet genarating function of $(p(n))_{n \geq 1}$ which is
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{p(n)}{n^s} &= \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{1}{n^s}\sum^{k}_{l = 0}p_l n^l \\
  &= \sum_{n \geq 1}\sum^{k}_{l = 0}\frac{p_l}{n^{s - l}} \\
  &= \sum^{k}_{l = 0} \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{p_l}{n^{s-l}} \\
  &= \sum^{k}_{l=0}p_l \zeta(s - l)
\end{align*}
where I used the absolute convergence for $\Re(s - k) > 1$ where $\mbox{deg}(p) = k$. Also
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{\log(n)}{n^s} &= \sum_{n \geq 2}\frac{\log(n)}{n^s} \\
  &= \sum_{n \geq 2}-\frac{d}{ds}\frac{1}{n^s} \\
  &= -\frac{d}{ds} \left( \sum_{n \geq }\frac{1}{n^s} \right) \\
  &= -\frac{d}{ds} \zeta(s) \\
  &= -\zeta'(s).
\end{align*}
I also calculated
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{q(\log n)}{n^s} &= \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{1}{n^s} \sum^{r}_{l=0}q_l \log(n)^l \\
  &= \sum_{n \geq 1}\sum^{r}_{l=0}(-1)^lq_l\frac{d^l}{ds^l} \frac{1}{n^s} \\
  &= \sum^{r}_{l=0}(-1)^l q_l \zeta^{(l)}(s).
\end{align*}
but I am not sure if I need this.
Now I am not sure if there is some result to calculate the dirichlet generating function of $(p(n)q(\log(n))_{n \geq 1}$ based on the previously calculated dirichlet generating functions.
Edit: From the comment I got
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{p(n) q(\log n)}{n^s} &= \sum_{n \geq 1} \left( \sum^{k}_{l = 0} q(\log n) \frac{p_l}{n^{s-l}} \right) \\
  &= \sum^{k}_{l = 0}p_l \sum_{n \geq 1}n^l \frac{q(\log n)}{n^{s}} \\
  &= \sum^{k}_{l = 0}p_l \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{n^l}{n^s} \sum^{r}_{m=0}q_m \log(n)^m   \\
  &= \sum^{k}_{l = 0}p_l \sum^{r}_{m = 0}q_m \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{1}{n^{s-l}} \log(n)^m   \\
  &= \sum^{k}_{l = 0}p_l \sum^{r}_{m = 0}q_m \sum_{n \geq 1}(-1)^m \frac{d^m}{ds^m} \frac{1}{n^{s-l}}  \\
  &= \sum^{k}_{l=0}p_l \sum^{r}_{m=0}(-1)^m q_m\zeta^{(m)}(s - l)
\end{align*}
I used the absolute convergence for $\Re(s - k - r) > 1$ where $\mbox{deg}(q) = r$ to interchange the order of summation. I am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: An idea is to start from your last line and consider $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^k  p_i  \sum_{n \geq 1} n^i \frac{q(\log n)}{n^s}$.  
Isn't a $(−1)^$ coefficient missing?

Comment: The coefficient $(-1)^l$ is in the derivative of the zeta function.

Comment: Concerning convergence we should impose $\,\Re s>k+1\,$ (since $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac {\log^m(n)}{n^s}=0\,$ for any positive $m$ and $s$) or use analytic continuation to obtain a "regularized result" as for $\zeta$.

Comment: You are right about (-1)^m. I have overseen that.